# PostGIS: nearest neighbour computation error "No space left on device"

Tags: postgis, error, query

I have two tables: `Table_1` and `Table_2`.

`Table_1` has 926019 rows.
`Table_2` has 3089 rows.

I want to update a field of `Table_1` with the distance to the closest item from `Table_2`.
Here is my query:

```
UPDATE Table_1
SET closest_distance = list.distance
FROM(
    SELECT T1.id AS name, MIN(T1.geom <-> T2.geom) AS distance
    FROM Table_1 AS T1
    CROSS JOIN Table_2 AS T2
    GROUP BY T1.id
    ORDER BY T1.id)
    AS list
WHERE Table_1.id = list.name;
```

When executing the query, after a long moment, I receive this error message:

```
Error: could not write the block 24453337 from temporary file : No space left on device
```

I think the solution is to execute the query by sets of rows (10k rows by 10k rows for example). I just do not know if this is possible on PostGIS, I have searched about it on PostgreSQL and found nothing relevant.

My question is: How can I complete my query ?

Comment: you need to create some more disc space

Comment: how can I do this ? I already have 186Go available on my disc.

Comment: This is more a PostgreSQL issue than PostGIS, and therefore more appropriate to [dba.se]. Just because you have space on a device doesn't mean you have space where the file is being created. A more complete description of your available devices and where PostgreSQL has been installed and configured will be necessary. Note that a cross join of 3k by 1m rows is 3g rows -- populated in the temp tablespace.

Comment: @JGH's answer is spot on; you are doing an unnecessary full cross join between your tables, with multiple costly operations, *for each row in the updated table* - and all that has to be kept in memory/extended disk memory until the transaction has completed! It's just not the way to handle `UPDATE` logic. (Btw. I read another answer of yours with this very query structure...you might want to revise that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside adding more disk space, you can try to modify the update query.

- No need to do the costly `order by` in the subquery
- No need to compute the distance between every entry in both tables at once. You can do it per row
- You can make use of a spatial index by moving the distance computation in the `order by` clause and keeping only the 1st result.

```sql
UPDATE Table_1
SET closest_distance = 
 (
    SELECT Table_1.geom <-> T2.geom AS distance
    FROM Table_2 AS T2
    ORDER BY Table_1.geom <-> T2.geom
    LIMIT 1 
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

When handling sorts, joins and other operations that require more space than you have memory for [Postgresql will store temporary files](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-file-layout.html) in `$PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp`. So you will need to make sure there is sufficient space on whichever disk that is.